# Como executar um script em uma pagina sem ter que abri-la em uma aba ou janela do navegador?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Preciso fazer uma web-extensão (add-on) que possa manipular elementos DOM, eventos existentes e executar scripts no contexto de um página de um site.

Mas preciso que isto ocorra em *background* sem que a página esteja explicitamente no navegador do usuário, ou seja, quero manipular uma página sem precisar abrir ela em uma aba ou janela?

Comment: Você tem que aprender a desenvolver **extensões** para o navegador chrome de preferência. No google tem vários tutoriais, exemplos, etc.

Comment: Qual o link da extensão que faz isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer isso é utilizando o `iframe`, abaixo um exemplo de como fazer (exemplos utilizando jquery).

Crie o iframe e coloque o style adequado para deixa-lo invisível para o usuário:

```
let iframe = "<iframe id='iframe' src='https://pt.stackoverflow.com' style='display:none;visibility:hidden' />";
$("body").append(iframe);
```

Para manusear os elementos dentro do iframe, utilize o `.contents`:

```
let page = $("#iframe").contents();
```

Agora só procurar pelos elementos:

```
page.find("input");
```

Comment: Acho que não é isso, a pergunta parece falar de manipular o próprio documento, não o conteúdo de outro frame.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ah, talvez eu não tenha explicado bem o meu problema na pergunta, mas isso resolveu-o. Sinta-se livre para edita-la ou me dar dicas de como melhora-la.

Comment: Hahaha, eu não vi que a pergunta era sua.

Comment: Mas continuo achando que você não entendeu a sua pergunta hahaha.

Comment: Francisco acho que o que o @bfavaretto quer dizer é que a sua resposta só explica a parte de como manipular o conteudo via iframe, mas não mostra um exemplo disto em uma extensão e sendo uma extensão pode ser necessário aplicar talvez alguma permissão que seja necessário. Vou tentar formular a resposta entre hoje e amanhã, no caso irei fornecer um exemplo com JS mesmo, mas com jQuery será só mudar algumas linhas

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Eu acho que a pergunta não está clara. Já reli várias vezes e continuo não entendendo o que ele quer fazer, mesmo com a resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto fui eu quem editou, não consegui me explicar melhor, só entendi mesmo o problema porque conversei com o AP, o básico é isto, *"como abrir e manipular uma página sem que ela precise estar aberta em uma aba ou janela"*, dá pra entender?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Li agora a versão original e entendi um pouco melhor.

Comment: É, entendi o que ele quer fazer de fato só depois de ler a versão original. Agora sua edição também está mais clara pra mim. @Guilh

Comment: @dvd cara por favor leva pro meta o questionamento do problema técnico do uso das tags e porque acha que esta errado, para de indagar o AP. Lá você vai receber a orientação ou talvez até provar o seu ponto de vista. Não é meu pensamento, é que você parece estar fazendo confusão e se você parece ter se confundido é provavel que não domine, não tem mal algum nisto, então por favor já chega de flood, tem um ponto de vista técnico sobre o assunto e uso das tags? Otimo! Posta no meta e resolve lá com a comunidade geral.